# Playing fragmented mp4 doesnt continue playing

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

Using ffmpeg I create an mp4 using my video camera as the source.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)"^
 -g 52^
 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3^
 -f mp4 -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe^
 %OUTPUT%\video.mp4
```

Works with IE11, Chrome and Firefox

And my html video tags:

```
<video controls autoplay style="width:640px;height:360px;">
  <source src="http://localhost/video.mp4" 
          type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

The node web server version just has src="http://localhost/" for the

using

I've tried nginx and a node version that I got from this [site](http://techqa.info/programming/question/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client) 
The nginx doesnt do anything special.  I just basically point the root to the folder so it sees the mp4.

The problem is it only plays however much the webserver sees when the page is loaded.  The file is still continuously growing.  And if I refresh the page I can see the time length is now longer since the last time.

My question is how can I make the video tag continuously play the fragmented video data without stopping and refreshing the page (which starts from the beginning again)?

Comment: I think it is not possible. Imagine that you have 30% of your content saved in  the video.mp4 at same time your html request the video file then it loads the mp4 metadata for 30% of video length and content, so you get only the 30%. What you need is a streaming solution, maybe using websockets or another solution. Maybe someone can contribute with another approach.

Comment: That is what I assumed also.  But going through google I saw info on mimicking live stream via fragmented.  But I think websockets may be the way to go

Comment: This is what Media Source Extensions (MSE) was invented for. Check out that technology.